# How do I check whether a particular File(identified by fileID) in my google drive using API whether its modified or not?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

How do I check whether a particular File(identified by fileID) in my google drive using API whether its modified or not ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) which will return the [file.resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)

File resource contains a lot of info about the file.

> version   long    A monotonically increasing version number for the file.
>   This reflects every change made to the file on the server, even those
>   not visible to the user.
>
> modifiedTime  datetime    The last time the file was modified by anyone
>   (RFC 3339 date-time). Note that setting modifiedTime will also update
>   modifiedByMeTime for the user.

There are a bunch more.  I guess its going to depend upon how you define been modified.  Are you storing last the last time you modified it someplace?  Do you just want to see if someone else changed it since you last changed it?